# Regions/code collapse in JavaScript? (Aptana studio)

Tags: javascript, aptana, region

is it possible to use "Region" code for JavaScript in Aptana Studio?
I found a post that you should go to "preferences -> aptana -> editor -> javascript -> select folding", but that doesn't tell me how to do it..

Is there a command, such as #region in visual studio?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That command is to control which areas are folded by default, but that's not the same as custom regions that you find in Visual Studio. If you'd like that feature, you might submit a feature request on the Aptana bug tracker. I couldn't find an existing ticket that covers it.

https://aptana.lighthouseapp.com/projects/35272-studio/tickets/new